# How do I list first level sub dirs only in Ant?

Tags: ant

Using Ant, how can I list sub folders only from the first level, and not going down the directory tree?

say I have:

```
dir1
-- dir21
----dir211
-- dir22

<dirset dir="dir1"/>
```

will list all dirs including `dir211`.
How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dirset like that :

```
<dirset dir="dir" includes="*"/>
```

or

```
<dirset dir="dir1">
 <include name="*"/>
</dirset>
```

**EDIT after comment**

`includes attribute` and `nested include name` should be equivalent, here's some
snippet working on my windows machine, given C:\foo\bar :

```
<project>
 <echo>
    ${ant.version}
    ${java.version}
    ${os.name}
 </echo>
 <dirset dir="c:/foo" includes="*" id="foobar" />

 <echo>${toString:foobar}</echo>


 <dirset dir="c:/foo" id="foobaz">
  <include name="*" />
 </dirset>

 <echo>${toString:foobaz}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
Buildfile: C:\rosebud\AntTest\tryme.xml
     [echo]     Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
     [echo]     1.7.0_02
     [echo]     Windows 7
     [echo]  
     [echo] bar
     [echo] bar
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: BTW, seems that the sub element <include> works fine, while the attribute 'includes' does not...

Comment: what ant + java version did you use ? Which OS ?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to include a date selector in my dirset and only choose the sub directories of my root directory so that meant I couldn't use `includes="*"`. My solution was to use the `<depth>` selector

```
<dirset dir="/myroot" excludes="*/*/**">
   <date datetime="${cuttoff_time}"
         pattern="${timeformat}"
         when="before"
         checkdirs="true" />
   <depth max="1" />
</dirset>
```